# Editing a web.config file through web application will cause any security problem?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

We developed an application to edit the web.config settings. The user has to locate the web.config file which they like to edit. Once their task is completed they can download the web.config file with the changes made by them. Since the web.config file has the database server information and passwords I have a concern that will it cause any security problem.
If so how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better encrypt your Connection string....

For ref [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(VS.80).aspx)

You can use the following method to secure the the webconfig.

if there exist the following code at web.config.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="yjsDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=HUAJLI-XP\SUN;Initial Catalog=yjsDB;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Then we can use the following code to protect it.

```
 protected void Encryption()
    {

        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
        ConfigurationSection section = config.ConnectionStrings;

        if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
            section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        }

    }
```

And you can use the following code to Decrypting it.

```
  protected void Decrypting()   
 {   
     Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);  
     ConfigurationSection section = config.ConnectionStrings;   

     if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)   
     {   
         section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();   
         section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;   
         config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);   
     }   
 }
```

Comment: I thought about this idea. But the client themselves will change their database password frequently. They will feel tough if we ask them to encrypt/decrypt the connection strings.

Comment: @gopal its upto you because you allow your clients to do so... If you trust them there wont be any problem regarding security.... But what happens when they try to cheat you?